# Loading many (thousands) rows and 3 columns from a spreadsheet into an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, excel-2016

I have a spreadsheet with 40K rows and 3 columns of strings that I need loaded into an array. How can I load an array such that I iterate through the sheet to load the values? Then end goal is that I fill the array so that I can then go through the array and say this value goes to this spreadsheet and that value goes in another spreadsheet. I have it working for a spreadsheet of 2 columns but the newest twist comes with 3 columns and trying to adapt my 2D version into 3D errors out.

```
ReDim arrTwoD(1 To intRows + 1, 1 To intCols + 1) 
For i = 1 To UBound(arrTwoD, 1)'really a 3D now. or at least it needs to be

  For j = 1 To UBound(arrTwoD, 2)
    For k = 1 To UBound(arrTwoD, 3)
    arrTwoD(i, j, k) = Sheets("ExistingLFItems").Cells(i, j, k)
    Debug.Print i, j, k, arrTwoD(i, j, k)
    Next k
  Next j
Next i
```

Comment: a spread sheet is only a 2D array.  There is no third dimension for Cells: `Cells(i, j, k)` what is k referring to in this instance?

Comment: Yep, I know it's wrong. k was my attempt at saying a 3rd column. Boiled down. I want to throw 40000 rows and 3 columns into an array

Comment: Declare ArrTwoD as variant. Then `ArrTwoD = Worksheets("ExistingLFItems").Range("A1:C40000").Value`

Comment: The first dimension is the rows, the second is the columns.  so `Ubound(arr,1)` is referring to the first dimension, the number of rows, `Ubound(arr,2)` is referring to the second dimension, the number of columns.  The number in the ubound is the dimension not the column number.  it is different than `arr(1,2)` which refers to the first row and second column of the arr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say We have ***3*** columns, **A**, **B**, and **C** with data from **A1** through **C40000**.  This will fill an array with the contents of these columns:

```
Sub RangeToArray()
    Dim arr() As Variant
    arr = Range("A1:C40000").Value
    MsgBox LBound(arr, 1) & "-" & LBound(arr, 2) & vbCrLf & UBound(arr, 1) & "-" & UBound(arr, 2)
End Sub
```

[image]

This is the exact equivalent of:

```
Dim arr(1 to 40000,1 to 3) As String
```

and filling the array with a double loop.

Comment: Actually you can Dim Arr without the ().

Answer (score 0):

No matter how hard you try, a sheet is only a 2D array.  You can simplify your code by doing something like:

```
Sub test()
Dim foo

     foo = Application.Transpose(Selection)

End Sub
```

Obviously you'll need to change 'Selection' to be your range, but this should get you started.  If you set a break point on End Sub and see what foo is, you'll notice that it is a 2D array where the first value is the column reference and the 2nd value is the row reference.

[image]

Also, as pointed out in the comments, you can omit the Transpose and do this:

```
Sub test()
Dim foo2

     foo2 = Sheet1.Range("A1:C3").Value

End Sub
```

Both yield the similar results.

Comment: Why the transpose?

Comment: quite honestly, because that's how I've always done it.  I just saw your comment in the question thread.  I'll give it a go....

Comment: @ScottCraner well shucky-darn...learned something new today...thanks for the tip!  Now i just need to remember that...

Comment: just an fyi: Application.Transpose has a limit, which in this case would be exceeded, it is something like 65,000 items.

Comment: interesting...I'll definitely keep that in mind.  Thanks for sharing!